# setting css class to a specific element in a user control

Tags: asp.net, navigation

I have made my left side navigation a user control and it has many links to various aspx pages such as

```
<a href="a.aspx" id="aPage">A</a>
<a href="b.aspx" id="bPage">B</a>
<a href="c.aspx" id="cPage">C</a>
```

Now when i am in a specific page say `A` i want to add a class say  `active` to the link `a.aspx`. What is the best approach to do this with as less code as possible. I have got this working by sending an integer parameter from the corresponding page and in the user control i am using a switch case to check the corresponding parameter and add class to the corresponding link but the code is quite big and i am sure there should be another easier way to do this.

Comment: is the navigation user control a databindable one? like a repeater, listview that has been modified to display links to pages

Comment: no its not, its just a plain unordered list with runat="server" for each link

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could do this with some javascript?
First get the current page name from the URL, then add a class to all a-elements where the href attribute contains that page name.

Here's an example and full explanation:
http://www.richnetapps.com/automatically_highlight_current_page_in/